# Combining PyQt and Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pyqt4

I want to combine my Ui generated by QtDesigner. I want to merge it with myplotlib so that everything is in one window. When i run the following code i get an error:

```
"QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on Ui_MainWindow "", which already has a layout
```

I know that i should connect my canvas layout with something but i dont know with what. I hope you can help me out here:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        # a figure instance to plot on
        self.figure = plt.figure()

        # this is the Canvas Widget that displays the `figure`
        # it takes the `figure` instance as a parameter to __init__
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        # this is the Navigation widget
        # it takes the Canvas widget and a parent
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

        # Just some button connected to `plot` method
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Plot')

        #self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.plot(data['time'], data['value']))
        #self.button.clicked.connect(self.plot)

        self.lineEditMomentum1 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEditMomentum1.setMaximumSize(200, 30)


        # set the layout
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEditMomentum1)

        self.setLayout(layout)


    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 390, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 420, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"))
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 450, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_3"))
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 480, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_4"))
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 510, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_5"))
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 540, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_6"))
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 430, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_7"))
        self.lineEdit_8 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 460, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_8"))
        self.lineEdit_9 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 490, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_9"))
        self.lineEdit_10 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 520, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_10"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 390, 61, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 420, 61, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 450, 71, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
        self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 480, 81, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
        self.label_5 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 510, 111, 20))
        self.label_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_5"))
        self.label_6 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 540, 111, 16))
        self.label_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_6"))
        self.label_7 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(585, 430, 51, 20))
        self.label_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_7"))
        self.label_8 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(585, 460, 51, 20))
        self.label_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_8"))
        self.label_9 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 400, 131, 16))
        self.label_9.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_9"))
        self.label_10 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 490, 31, 16))
        self.label_10.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_10"))
        self.label_11 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 520, 71, 16))
        self.label_11.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_11"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 370, 251, 91))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 127, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(63, 63, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 170))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(37, 88, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 127, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.NoRole, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 127, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(63, 63, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 170))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(37, 88, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 127, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.NoRole, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 127, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(63, 63, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 170))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 127))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.NoRole, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        self.pushButton.setPalette(palette)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 460, 251, 91))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)  
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Momentum 1", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Momentum 2", None))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Friction ratio 1", None))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Friction ratio 2", None))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Number of teeth, N1", None))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Number of teeth, N2", None))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Initial time", None))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Final time", None))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Differential parameters", None))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Step", None))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Initial angle", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Plot", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Set Default Values", None))
```

Comment: Don't use pyplot with embedding.  See QT examples here http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/index.html

Comment: I still can't figure this out. Could u say something more please? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [minimal stand-alone program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that still produces your error is:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Ui_MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

As you can see it is unrelated to integrating matplotlib in PyQt. The problem is that `QMainWindow` must have a central widget which acts as a container for all your child widgets. This central widget has its own layout,  the layout of the `QMainWindow` is for toolbars and dock widgets (see the illustration in http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html). Note that you should add toolbars with the `addToolbar()` method.

The fix to your error is thus:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_widget.setLayout(layout)        
        # The main_widget is a container to which you
        # can add your child widgets here...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Ui_MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

Now, your code example contains another error, which is the one that @tcaswell provided an answer for. If you build the fix into your program you will see that the figure canvas will end up in its own, separate window.

Again, a minimal-ish example is:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import \
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import \
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        # use addToolbar to add toolbars to the main window directly!
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.addToolBar(self.toolbar)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Plot')
        self.lineEditMomentum1 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEditMomentum1.setMaximumSize(200, 30)

        self.main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEditMomentum1)

        self.main_widget.setLayout(layout)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Ui_MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

When combining matplotlib in PyQt, don't use the matlab-like interface of the `pyplot` module at all. Use the matplotlib classes directly.

Change `plt.figure()` in `Figure()` like so:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg \
    import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg \
    import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.figure = Figure() # don't use matplotlib.pyplot at all!
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        # use addToolbar to add toolbars to the main window directly!
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.addToolBar(self.toolbar)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Plot')
        self.lineEditMomentum1 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEditMomentum1.setMaximumSize(200, 30)

        self.main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEditMomentum1)

        self.main_widget.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Ui_MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

Finally, you might consider to create your programs without using the Qt Designer. You will gain a lot of insight by building them from scratch, your code will be more readable and it will be easier to make minimal working examples of your problems. I think the extra time it takes to type the widget statements will pay itself back.

Comment: @titusjan Thank you for your answer. It is very good! My code is pretty similar to the code above, but I use matplotlib.pyplot.gcf().autofmt_xdate(). I need it because I am dealing with dates. Is this bad? Why shouldn't one use matplotlib.pyplot?

Comment: @feinmann: according to [this comment by tcaswell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973177/matplotlib-and-pyqt-dynamic-figure-runs-slow-after-several-loads-or-looks-messy#comment26295260_17973177) (who is co-lead developer at Matplotlib) "pyplot sets up its own gui, mainloop and canvas". This interferes with Qt. Since you can't use pyplot there is no current figure and no `gcf()`. Therefore use `self.figure.autofmt_xdate()` instead