# When matplotlib is embedded in PyQt4 how are axes/subplots labelled without using pyplot?

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt4

It's easy with pyplot but apparently [pyplot shouldn't be used when embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992771/combining-pyqt-and-matplotlib#comment48109095_29992771). I haven't been able to find any non-pyplot embedding examples where labels are used.

Comment: This is a bad question and not what I intended to ask but I won't delete it because there is already an answer. I meant to ask about legends in embedded plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you found this [page](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html), too. Maybe [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/winpython/pyqtdesignerplugins/ci/default/tree/matplotlibwidget.py) example helps. I have not tested it, thus I cannot say if it works.

Staying with the example from the matplotlib example, the labels in the subplot `self.axes` can be set using `self.axes.set_xlabel(x Label")` or `self.axes.set_ylabel("y Label")`.