# How to avoid importing pyplot in embedded qt4 GUI?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, pyqt4

"According to this [SO note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973177/matplotlib-and-pyqt-dynamic-figure-runs-slow-after-several-loads-or-looks-messy#comment26295260_17973177), one should not import pyplot when embedding. It does funky things like running its own GUI with its own main loop."

If so, how can one pass the matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes argument necessary for a Slider without invoking plt.axes()?
In the GUI [based on matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html), we have [added the following to include a slider]:

```
 def compute_initial_figure(self):
        ymax = 300
        window_size=1
        res= 0.1
        ax= self.axes
        t = np.arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.1)
        s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
        ax.plot(t, s)
        ax.axis([0, window_size, -ymax, ymax])
        ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
        axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
        axpos = plt.axes([.1, .1, 0.75, 0.05], axisbg=axcolor) #MAKES OWN FIG!
        spos = Slider(axpos, 'Time', res, t[-1], valinit=0)
        spos.on_changed(update)
```

The axpos line uses plt and creates its own figure separate from the Qt window. Note plt.axes returns a a matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes object not a matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object. 

**Similar questions:**
[When matplotlib is embedded in PyQt4 how are axes/subplots labelled without using pyplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289117/when-matplotlib-is-embedded-in-pyqt4-how-are-axes-subplots-labelled-without-usin)

[Combining PyQt and Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992771/combining-pyqt-and-matplotlib#comment48109095_29992771)

Comment: Page http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html does not seem to have that kind of `compute_initial_figure()`.

Comment: Correct, this is a modifed compute_initial_figure(): to include a slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plt.axes` function adds an axes to the current figure by getting the current figure and then calling `figure.add_axes`. Instead of getting the current figure you must keep a reference to the figure when you create it. If you look at http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html, you can see how a figure should be created. I would take that example as a starting point.

So, to keep a reference to the figure change the relevant line into:

```
self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
```

Then call the add_axes method like this:

```
axpos = self.fig.add_axes([.1, .1, 0.75, 0.05], axisbg=axcolor)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. It seems fig.axes is TYPE:<type 'list'> and not  matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes so it produces a TypeError: 'list' object is not callable. Still working it out.

Comment: Ah, I didn't look right. Looking again at the source of `pyplot.axes` I see that it calls `add_axes` on the current figure. I will update my post above.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Also, for the purposes of the slider:
1) It wants canvas defined (self.canvas= FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)) before the compute_initial_figure(). 
2) Similarly, in the example the figure is defined as fig but I changed it to sel.fig to facilitate using it later.