# using ginput in embedded matplotlib figure in PyQt4

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt4, ginput

I'm trying to use the 'ginput' to measure distance in a matplotlib figure by allowing the user to mouse click the locations. I am able to do this independently in the matplotlib figure, but I'm having problems when I tried to set the figure onto a matplotlib canvas and then embed it into PyQt4 widget. Below is my code, most of which were taken from the matplotlib examples. My solution will be to click a set of locations, and pass the (x,y) coordinates to the 'dist_calc' function to get the distance.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import random
import numpy as np

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
    self.fig = Figure((6.5, 5.0), tight_layout=True)
    self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

    self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Plot')
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.plot)

    self.ndist = QtGui.QPushButton('Measure')
    self.ndist.clicked.connect(self.draw_line)

    self.toolbar.addWidget(self.button)
    self.toolbar.addWidget(self.ndist)
    self.fig.tight_layout()
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
    layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
    self.setLayout(layout)

def plot(self):
    data = [random.random() for i in range(20)]
    self.ax.hold(False)                          
    self.ax.plot(data, '*-')                     
    self.canvas.draw()                      

def draw_line(self):
    self.xy = plt.ginput(0)
    x = [p[0] for p in self.xy]
    y = [p[1] for p in self.xy]
    self.ax.plot(x,y)
    self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    self.get_dist(x, y)

def get_dist(self, xpts, ypts):
    npts = len(xpts)
    distArr = []
    for i in range(npts-1):
        apt = [xpts[i], ypts[i]]
        bpt = [xpts[i+1], ypts[i+1]]
        dist =self.calc_dist(apt,bpt)
        distArr.append(dist)

    tdist = np.sum(distArr)
    print(tdist)

def calc_dist(self,apt, bpt):
    apt = np.asarray(apt)
    dist = np.sum((apt - bpt)**2)
    dist = np.sqrt(dist)
    return dist

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Window()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973177/matplotlib-and-pyqt-dynamic-figure-runs-slow-after-several-loads-or-looks-messy#comment26295260_17973177) by one of the lead Matplotlib developers, you must **not** import `pyplot` when you're embedding Matplotlib in Qt. Pyplot sets up its own gui, mainloop and canvas, which interfere with the Qt event loop.

Changing the line `self.xy = plt.ginput(0)` into `self.xy = self.fig.ginput(0)` did not help but gave an insightful error:

```
AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasQTAgg' object has no attribute 'manager'
Figure.show works only for figures managed by pyplot, normally created by pyplot.figure().
```

In short, I don't think this is possible. `ginput` is a blocking function and seems only to be implemented for a Matplotlib event loop. I'm afraid that you will have to build the functionality you want using [Matplotlib mouse events](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/event_handling.html), which *do* work when embedding in PyQt. Just be sure not to use pyplot!

**Edit**: I just remembered, perhaps the [LassoSelector](http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.LassoSelector) is what you need.