# pyplot example with QT Designer

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt4, qt-designer

I have seen many examples of integrating matplotlib with python2.6 and QT4 Designer using mplwidget and they work fine.  I now need to integrate a pyplot with QT4 Designer but cannot find any examples. All of my attempts to integrate a pyplot graphic have ended in a seg fault.   Can someone please direct me to a working example using Designer and pyplot?

**Follow up**:
Okay, so I tried your solution but I'm still having issues.  Unfortunately the machine I use for this code is not hooked up to the internet, so below is a fat finger of the pertinent parts of the code I am using:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import MatplotlibWidget     # This is the code snippet you gave in your answer

.
.
.
def drawMap(self) :

    fig = plt.figure()  

    map = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlat = -90.0, urcrnrlat = 90.0, llcrnrlon = -180.0, urcrnrlon = 180.0, resolution = 'c')
    map.drawcoastlines()
    map.drawcountries()
    plt.show()


def drawMap_Qt(self) :

    self.ui.PlotWidget.figure = plt.figure()  # This is the Qt widget promoted to MatplotlibWidget

    map = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlat = -90.0, urcrnrlat = 90.0, llcrnrlon = -180.0, urcrnrlon = 180.0, resolution = 'c')
    map.drawcoastlines()
    map.drawcountries()
    self.ui.PlotWidget.show()
```

The function drawMap() works fine.  It creates a separate window and plots the map.  The drawMap_Qt() function results in a segmentation fault with no other errors.  The end goal is to plot a contour on top of the map.  I can do this with the drawMap() function.  Of course, I can't even get to the contour part with the drawMap_Qt() function.  Any insights as to why it is seg faulting would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to the mplwidget from [Python(x,y)](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) and [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/), I think it does use pyplot, but I had trouble putting it in my python install so I just used this class:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

class MatplotlibWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MatplotlibWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.figure = Figure(*args, **kwargs)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

See also [How to embed matplotib in pyqt - for Dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459811/how-to-embed-matplotib-in-pyqt-for-dummies).

Then in Qt Designer you need to create a promoted class, with base class: QWidget, promoted class name: MatplotlibWidget, and header file: the python script containing the MatplotlibWidget class (without the .py). You can add things like `ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)`, `line = ax.plt(...)` within the class or by calling methods of the figure attribute of an instance of the class.

**Edit:**
So I was a bit wrong before, in general with embedded matplotlib widgets you need to use the object oriented methods and not the functions in pyplot. ([This](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related) sort of explains what the difference is.) Using my snippet above as mymatplotlibwidget.py, try something like this. I don't have basemap installed, so this is somewhat of a guess, but from the examples you need to tell Basemap which axes to use.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from mymatplotlibwidget import MatplotlibWidget

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = MatplotlibWidget()
fig = widget.figure
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
map = Basemap(..., ax=ax)
fig.canvas.draw()
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Okay, so I couldn't get that to work -- please see update to the original question

Comment: See my edit above, and you shouldn't call plt.figure() because the widget already has a figure within it.