# Boxplot not showing up when used with pyQt

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, boxplot

I was playing with boxplot (and bxp) in Python. For integretion with pyQt I used code from [matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html) and [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459811/how-to-embed-matplotib-in-pyqt-for-dummies).
When I'm drawing boxplot in popup, it works fine. When I try to draw some simple plot on the canvas in pyQt (like sin, or like in the examples above), it works fine.

The problem is when i try to draw boxplot on my canvas in pyQt window, only fliers are shown.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there other way to show boxplot in pyQt window?

It looks like this: [image]

My code -s tandalone version

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [{'med': 6.0, 'q1': 4.0, 'q3': 8.0, 'whislo': 3.0, 'whishi': 10.0, 'fliers': [20, 1]}]
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.bxp(data)
plt.show()
```

Overrided plot method from [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12465861/1536976):

```
    data = [{'med': 6.0, 'q1': 4.0, 'q3': 8.0, 'whislo': 3.0, 'whishi': 10.0, 'fliers': [20, 1]}]
    ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
    ax.hold(False)
    ax.bxp(data)
    self.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: I get an error when executing your first example (TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not iterable). Which Python/pyqt/matplotlib version do you use.

Comment: Sorry, typo. `fig, axes = plt.subplot()` should be `fig, axes = plt.subplots()`. I fixed it in the question.
myplotlib 1.4.2, python 3.4.2, pyqt 4.11

Comment: I can confirm now what you see (also in PySide), but I cannot help you. Sorry.

Comment: I've answered your question and I hope the solution I provided you will work for you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I've searched for solutions but could not find any good hint. But then I tried to play a little bit
with the code. And somehow it works now (the problem is the line ax.hold(False):

If you call it like this (code from your question):

```
data = [{'med': 6.0, 'q1': 4.0, 'q3': 8.0, 'whislo': 3.0, 'whishi': 10.0, 'fliers': [20, 1]}]
ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
ax.hold(False) // call hold BEFORE bxp(data)
ax.bxp(data)
self.canvas.draw()
```

This does not work. But now call hold AFTER bxp(data) and it works (I tested it and it worked).

```
data = [{'med': 6.0, 'q1': 4.0, 'q3': 8.0, 'whislo': 3.0, 'whishi': 10.0, 'fliers': [20, 1]}]
ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
ax.bxp(data)
ax.hold(False) // call hold AFTER bxp(data)
self.canvas.draw()
```

The second version works fine ;)
I hope I could help you with this answer.