# how to draw Chart from csv file which using pyplot in Pyside/Python

Tags: python, charts, pyside

I want to build an app, using PySide, that creates a chart with the pyplot library.

I have one button:

```
qbutton1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Open File")
```

If the button is clicked, a CSV file is loaded with this function:

```
def openFile (self):

    path, _ = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Open file','','CSV(*.csv)')

    self.loadCsv(path);
    self.fileName=path

   #self.textlink.setText(str(path)) # this code have trouble , because when i clicked my button it talk that it not attribute in class.
```

I have a CSV file with 2 columns:

*1,4
3,5 
4,9*

I'd want this chart to be drawn on a QtextEdit like the following:

```
textbox= QtGui.QTextEdit()
```

Answer (score 0):

`QTextEdit` is made for editable text blocks, not for plotting graphs.

`matplotlib` provides custom Qt widgets to embed plots in a PyQt/PySide app. You can have a look at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459811/how-to-embed-matplotib-in-pyqt-for-dummies) for more info on embedding matplolib in PyQt, or have a look at [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html), taken from the matplotlib documentation.

Comment: layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout() t
you're referring to this QT Widget?

Comment: No, `FigureCanvasQtAgg` (imported like this: `from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas`) is the one rendering the plot. Maybe you can copy the example given in that question and use it as a base. Don't forget to mark this answer if it solves your problem!