# Adding a few pandas plots in one PyQT Gui window

Tags: python, pandas, plot, pyqt

i want add my plot to pyqt ui

i am using pandas for plot.

```
data= pandas.DataFrame(pandas.read_sql(sql, my_connection))
data[data['GENERAL_TYPE']=='phone'].pivot_table('CEID','CONTACTED_PERSON_NEW','RESULT',  aggfunc='count').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(10,10))
data[data['GENERAL_TYPE']=='phone'].pivot_table(['CEID'],['CONTACTED_PERSON_NEW'],['DATA4_CAMP'],  aggfunc='count').plot(kind='bar',figsize=(10,10), stacked=True)
data[data['GENERAL_TYPE']=='phone'].pivot_table(['CEID'],['CONTACTED_PERSON_NEW'],  aggfunc='count').plot(kind='pie',subplots=True, legend=False, stacked=False, figsize=(10,10))
```

and after this i have few plots :

How i can use this example([How to embed matplotib in pyqt - for Dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459811/how-to-embed-matplotib-in-pyqt-for-dummies)) 
add my plots to different layouts in one window ?

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided does not run for me plus it contains an error, as stated in one of the comments. When embedding in PyQt you cannot use `plt.figure()` because this will start its own event loop. You must use `matplotlib.Figure()` instead. I strongly recommend that you base your code on [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html) from the Matplotlib documentation, instead of on the 'for Dummies' answer.

If you got a regular Matplotlib plot working in PyQt, you can move on and try a Pandas plot. I don't know much about Pandas but it seems to me that Pandas plots to the current axes by default. This will not work when embedding in PyQt; `plt.figure()` sets the current axes, but we must use `matplotlib.Figure()` so there is no current axis. However, I think that the Pandas plot command accepts an `ax` keyword parameter. This allows you to pass your own axes object instead (which is defined with `self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)` in the example)

In the Matplotlib example you can try to replace

```
self.axes.plot(...)
```

with your Pandas plot command and pass `ax=self.axes`. Something like this

```
data[...].pivot_table(...).plot(ax=self.axes, ...)
```

If that doesn't work I would ask the Pandas community. I will add a tag.