# Plotting with matplotlib after changing rows in qlistwidget

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I want to plot charts after clicking on rows. The signal is transmitted, but the chart isn't plotted. But if I call a plotting function (`self.hist()`) from `MyPlot.__init__`, the chart is plotted.

I used this as an example, but it didn't help. [How to embed matplotib in pyqt - for Dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459811/how-to-embed-matplotib-in-pyqt-for-dummies)

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QListWidget, QListWidgetItem, QApplication, QMessageBox
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import sqlite3
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# my plotting functions are in this class
class Myplot(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.fig = Figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        #self.hist()    

#this and next functions should plot
    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.axes.hold(False)
        self.axes.plot(np.random.rand(400))
        self.draw()
    def hist(self):
        tm = pd.Series(np.random.randn(500), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2005', periods=500))
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.axes.hold(False)
        tm = tm.cumsum()
        self.axes.plot(tm)
        self.draw()

#list with rows. I want to draw charts after clicking on them
class Panel (QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QListWidget.__init__(self)
        self.row1 = "COMMISSIONS & FEES"
        self.addItem(self.row1)
        row2 = "NET LIQUIDATING VALUE"
        self.addItem(row2)
        self.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.itemClicked.connect(self.Clicked)

#this function sends signal to the plotting functions
    def Clicked(self):
        mplot=Myplot()
        index=self.currentRow()
        if index == 0:
            print '0000'
            mplot.compute_initial_figure()
        if index == 1:
            print '1111'
            mplot.hist()

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        #menu
        exitAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('Stuff/exit.png'), '&Exit', self)        
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(QtGui.qApp.quit)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')        

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')
        self.showMaximized()
        self.setMinimumSize(600, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('ESPA')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('Stuff/icon.png.'))

        #setup window widgets
        self.main_widget= QtGui.QWidget(self)
        #lines up widgets horizontally
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        mp=Myplot(self.main_widget)
        p=Panel(self.main_widget)
        layout.addWidget(p)
        layout.addWidget(mp)
        self.main_widget.setFocus()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```