# Example of animated 3D bar-chart using matplotlib.animation in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I've seen a few nice examples of use of `matplotlib.animation` module, including this [animated 3D plot example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_3danim.html). I'm wondering if this animation module can be used with a `bar3d` chart.

Can someone generates a simple example of that?

**Note:** I'm currently working on a different solution that doesn't include `matplotlib.animation` (see my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35415669/animated-3d-bar-chart-with-python)) but this appears to be too slow...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a small example with 2x2 bars which will be growing and changing color randomly, one at a time when `update_bars()` is called:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random

def update_bars(num, bars):
    i = random.randint(0, 3)
    dz[i] += 0.1
    bars[i] = ax.bar3d(xpos[i], ypos[i], zpos[i], dx[i], dy[i], dz[i], color=random.choice(['r', 'g', 'b']))
    return bars

fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)
xpos = [1, 1, 3, 3]
ypos = [1, 3, 1, 3]
zpos = [0, 0, 0, 0]
dx = [1, 1, 1, 1]
dy = [1, 1, 1, 1]
dz = [3, 2, 6, 5]

# add bars
bars = []
for i in range(4):
    bars.append(ax.bar3d(xpos[i], ypos[i], zpos[i], dx[i], dy[i], dz[i], color=random.choice(['r', 'g', 'b'])))
ax.set_title('3D bars')

line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_bars, 20, fargs=[bars], interval=100, blit=False)
plt.show()
```

Output (not animated here):

[image: plot]

Comment: This is a great example! Thank you! I just want to point out some problems. (1) The program runs slower and slower as it is animating the graph. (2) The bars are somehow being superimposed, so only the biggest value of `dz` is represented, not the current value. That can be seen by replacing `dz[i] += 0.1` by `dz[i] -= 0.1`.

Comment: If you put <code>bars[i].remove()</code> before `<code>`bars[i] = ax.bar3d(xpos[i], ..."</code> it works in either <code>dz[i] -= 0.1</code> or <code>dz[i] += 0.1</code>.

Comment: And you can put <code>dz[i] += random.choice([-0.1, 0.1])</code> in place of <code>dz[i] += 0.1</code> for a better test.