# Display Matplotlib plot from PyQT - new window?

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, plot, pyqt

Question about PyQt4 GUI and Matplotlib plots. 
I have standard PyQt GUI (call it "master_GUI.py") with buttons that call external modules (let's call it "slave.py") to do read/store data, do calculations based on that data, and create Matplotlib plots. I have no issues creating/displaying the plots when I just run "slave.py." But if I call that program from "master_GUI.py," I do not get any plots displayed. I know "slave.py" is called.

Q: If I want to display any Matplotlib plot(s) through a PyQT GUI, do I need to embed it into the GUI window? or is there an easy way to create plots in a new window through my standalone "slave.py"? How would I do the later?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459811/how-to-embed-matplotib-in-pyqt-for-dummies)

Comment: Thanks. So if I want to be able to connect Matplotlib plots with the PyQT UI, then I embedding is the only option?

Comment: I believe that's the simplest way. I can't imagine someone maintaining two graphical toolkits (Qt and Tk) at the same time.

Comment: I see! Thank you. I'll look into it