# How to put an DICOM image inside GUI in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, pyqt4, qtgui

I need to load a DICOM file and put the image in one part of my GUI window. I am using Python 3.4, PyQt4.

Is it possible to do it with matplotlib.pyplot?

Comment: Are you expecting someone to write a DICOM viewer in PyQt for you? Otherwise, can you be more specific about the actual problem? Is it the loading of DICOM images, is it the visualization, is it the pyqt part that prevents you from advancing your task?

Comment: The loading part is not a problem. The visualization is the problem, as I know how to do it with pyplot.imshow() and pyplot.show(), but I don't know how to put it in the part of the GUI window that I want it to be there.
Basically, if I want my GUI to have a button and an image(which is DICOM), what should I use to put that image there?

Comment: What about this question here: [How to embed matplotib in pyqt - for Dummies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459811/how-to-embed-matplotib-in-pyqt-for-dummies).