# Plot figure object in a specific figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, figure, matplotlib-widget

I have an object from a black box of type:

`<matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes object at 0x7fedbe19c1d0>`

I would like to plot it in a matplotlibwidget, in my pyqt5 GUI.

The problem is: How to plot my object in a specific figure?

I tried this:

`myObject = blackBox()
 myObject_figure = myObject.get_figure()
 myObject_figure.show()`

So here I can plot my `<matplotlib.figure.Figure>` object in a new figure, but I would like to plot it in a specific figure...

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly,you can use matplotlib.pyplot.subplot for the same. you can have a look at the examples in this link for starters https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html

Comment: But the subplot doesn't help me to plot a figure object in a specific figure.

Comment: so you want to bind a figure object to to your pyqt5 GUI widget? Is this what you want?

Comment: Hope this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459811/how-to-embed-matplotlib-in-pyqt-for-dummies?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Excatly! I know how to embed matplotlib in pyqt. But I don't have any data to plot, I just have a matplotlib object...
So how to plot a matplotlib object ?

I can use, as I said, the show() method, but it create a new figure. I want to "show()" my object in my pyqt5 GUI.

Comment: have you tried the .get_xdata() and .get_ydata() methods

Comment: Those methods doesn't exist

Comment: Do u mind sharing your code snippet of the black box()

Comment: This is a link only answer that has only merit as long as the link exists. Please flesh out your answer so that is is stand-alone, and can help solve this problem even if the link is down. ... I think you get the idea...