# FigureCanvas is never shown even when draw is called

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to embed a matplotlib figure in my QT application, using which I want to show different plots upon different user actions.

I have created a custom figure canvas, in which I initialize a figure and a subplot. The code is as followed:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import FigureCanvasQT, FigureManagerQT
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class CustomFigureCanvas(FigureCanvasQT):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, cmap_name="coolwarm"):
        fig = plt.Figure()
        self.color_map = plt.get_cmap(cmap_name)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super().__init__(fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.setBaseSize(300, 300)
        self.setMaximumSize(400, 400)
        self.setMinimumSize(250, 250)
        self.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
        )

    def set_clf_2d(self, clf_2d):
        self.clf = clf_2d

    def plot_new_datapoints(self, x2D):
        self.add_datapoint(x2D)

    @staticmethod
    def _make_meshgrid(x, y, h=0.02):
        x_min, x_max = x.min() - 1, x.max() + 1
        y_min, y_max = y.min() - 1, y.max() + 1
        XX, YY = np.meshgrid(
            np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h)
        )
        return XX, YY

    def _plot_contours(self, xx, yy, **params):
        """Plot the decision boundaries for a classifier.

        Parameters
        ----------
        ax: matplotlib axes object
        clf: a classifier
        xx: meshgrid ndarray
        yy: meshgrid ndarray
        params: dictionary of params to pass to contourf, optional
        """
        Z = self.clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
        Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
        self.axes.contourf(xx, yy, Z, **params)

    def plot_data(self, x2D, y):
        """plots the given array and the decision function bounday.

        Arguments:
            x2D {np.array} -- [2d array]
            y {np.array} -- [1d array]
        """

        x0, x1 = x2D[:, 0], x2D[:, 1]
        xx, yy = CustomFigureCanvas._make_meshgrid(x0, x1)
        labels = ["Cognitive", "Not Cognitive"]
        colors = ["r", "b"]
        self.axes.clear()
        self._plot_contours(xx, yy, cmap=self.color_map, alpha=0.8)
        target_ids = [0, 1]
        for i, c, label in zip(target_ids, colors, labels):
            print(i, label)
            self.axes.scatter(
                x0[y == i, 0],
                x1[y == i, 1],
                color=c,
                label=label,
                marker="o",
                s=(15, 15),
            )

        self.axes.set_xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
        self.axes.set_ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
        self.axes.set_title("2D Representation using PCA")
        self.axes.legend(fontsize=8)
        self.axes.plot()

    def add_datapoint(self, x2d):
        """Adds a new datapoint to the plot

        Arguments:
            x2d {a 2d single point, [x,y]} -- [np.array with shape (1,2)]
            axes {plt.axes} -- [description]

        """
        print(x2d, type(x2d))
        self.axes.scatter(
            x2d[:, 0],
            x2d[:, 1],
            color="k",
            label="Current Text",
            marker="o",
            s=(15, 15),
        )
        self.axes.legend(fontsize=8)
```

My problem is that whatever I do, my FigureCanvas will always be filled with black, and won't be changed on any circumstances.

By using the CustomFigureCanvas you can reproduce my problem.

[image: My problem. The black widget is my figure canvas.]

Comment: Can you make a smaller [reprex]?  I can't test this code (it's not complete) and I think you may need to change the way you configure matplotlib (which isn't shown in this code).

Comment: @strubbly I have updated my post and put some classes that I had forgotten to put before. This is my whole UI package and is detached from my models and controller packages(which are many). I only use Matplotlib in my UI classes.

Comment: Remove everything that isn't needed for the problem you are asking about. See [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

So I was just trying to mimic what was written in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459811/how-to-embed-matplotlib-in-pyqt-for-dummies), and I tried using `FigureCanvasQTAgg` instead of `FigureCanvasQT` and suddenly everything started to work. I don't know why this exists, and the pyqt documentation is very unclear about these kinds of differences.

Comment: Maybe [this makes things clearer](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend). Basically, to draw something using matplotlib you need both a renderer (the thing that does the drawing) and a canvas (the place where things are drawn on). `FigureCanvasQT` only provides a canvas; to use it you would still need a renderer. `FigureCancasQtAgg` is based on `FigureCanvasQT` but includes an AGG rendering engine as well.